# How to check neighbours in an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have created an array of arrays in Ruby with elements populated in it. Is there a clean way to check all neighbouring elements of a specific element in a multi-dimensional array instead of doing:

```
array[x-1][y]
array[x][y-1]
array[x-1][y-1]
array[x+1][y]
array[x][y+1]
array[x+1][y+1]
array[x+1][y-1]
array[x-1][y+1]
```

The method above seems redundant, I feel ruby must have an easier way to do the above.

An example of my array looks like this:

```
# SA[
     #  R0[S,X, S, S, S,]
     #  R1[Z,Y, , , , ]
     #  R2[ , , , , , ]
     #  R3[ , , , , , ] 
#   ]
```

In the example above, the neighbours of Y are S,X and Z.

Comment: Real data and constructors, please. Ruby doesn't have 2D arrays, so you need to describe your actual data and expected results.

Comment: Also, given `a = [1, 2, 3]` what do you think `a[0-1]` gives you? The answer may surprise you.

Comment: Check neighbours for what?  Pathological tendencies?

Comment: @CodeGnome, I have given an example of the data, let me know if that clarifies things for you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I like this version better, but perhaps you would like to experiment with products?

```
[x-1, x, x+1].product([y-1, y, y+1]) - [x, y]
```

Or ranges?

```
((x-1) .. (x+1)).to_a.product(((y-1)..(y+1)).to_a) - [x, y]
```

Comment: This would work, but still needs to check if the cells are within the bounds of the grid. OP's original code is better in terms of clarity and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't really do 2d arrays like some other languages since arrays are mutable. I don't know of any built-in Ruby classes that handle this kind of thing, and really, there are so many combinations of things that you might want to do and questions that must be asked. How do you handle the edge cases? Ignore, wrap-around? Are you summing? Applying a function to each, is that function constant or is there a falloff of sorts? What result are you looking for - mutate, create new? Is this just for this kernel size or do you want to generalize it for different sizes?

My advice would be to create your own class for handling 2d arrays (internally represented as a 1d array). The code you're looking to write is simple, but you knowing exactly what you want means that you can answer all the questions that I asked about (plus the ones I didn't) and abstract all that stuff out of wherever you're looking to use it. Also, you can generalize it only to the level that you need so that you can optimize it as well as possible (Ruby is very flexible, but maybe not the fastest of languages).

Answer (score 0):

This solution gives `i` and `j` indexes for each neighbour. These values are mapped to values (neighbours).

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 5, 6],
    [8, 89, 44, 0],
    [8, 7, 23, 0],
    [6, 9, 3, 0]
  ]
  
  def neighbours(array, (i , j)) 
    [
      [i, j - 1],
      [i, j + 1],
      [i - 1, j - 1],
      [i - 1, j],
      [i - 1, j + 1],
      [i + 1, j - 1],
      [i + 1, j],
      [i + 1, j + 1],
    ].select { |h, w|
        h.between?(0, array.length - 1) && w.between?(0, array.first.length - 1)
      }.map do |row, col|
          array[row][col]
      end 
  end
  
  array.each_with_index do |row, i|
    row.each_with_index do |col, j|
      p(array[i][j], neighbours(array, [i, j]))
    end 
  end
```